# Why would Task Manager show Windows Camera Frame Service under an app that doesn't use a camera?

Tags: security, task-manager, camera, windows-services, surveillance

Task Manager shows "Windows Camera Frame Service" active under an app.  But the app doesn't use the camera for anything.  Indeed, the app is an intellectual property app that, were it known involves the camera in any way, would probably put the company out of business.

So, before I go putting a company, that may be innocent, out of business, is there any reason for the "Windows Camera Frame Service" to show up in an app that doesn't use the camera at all?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of Task Manager? You may hide the name of the process in question.

Comment: Done.  I'm not sure what this does for you other than verifies that I did indeed have an app running that used the service (and a little bit of a GPU).  I'm really careful about this for reasons that should be obvious.

Comment: Have you checked the app at VirusTotal?

Comment: VirusTotal issues a clean bill of health.